# Your yo version is outdated

Tags: npm, yeoman, npm-install

I'm getting the following error when I try to install Yeoman on Ubuntu using npm install -g yo:

[image: Error installing Yo]

Despite having the latest version 2.0.3 installed, I'm getting this issue. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try `npm install -g yo@latest` ?

Comment: Yup.
It didn't work...

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: Any updates? I'm having the same issue with updating to yo version 3.1.0.

Comment: In my case issue solved by `npm install --global yo` , updated to version `3.1.1`

Answer (score -2):

uninstall node js.

Remove npm and npm cache file from  \AppData\Roaming